# Editar tablas en Django

Tags: python, django

¿como podría editar una tabla ya creada en Django? me gustaria editar la longitud (lenght) de la columna ***Horario***, no se si se puede, o debo crearla otra vez ya corregida.

```
 class PlantillaPerfilSocioVistaPrevia(models.Model):
    NombreNegocio = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Horario = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    FrasePresentacion = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    CoordenadasMapa = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    FotoPerfil = models.CharField(max_length=150)

class PlantillaPerfilSocioOfertas(models.Model):
    Titulo = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ImagenFondo = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Comment: si se puede solo debes generar los seed y ejecutar el comando pertinente

Answer (score 0):

Si claro, primero realiza tu cambio en el código de los modelos, guardas el fichero y acto seguido realiza un migrate. No debería de darte problemas.

Comment: Funciono, gracias!!!